# ASP.NET Authentication "Remember Me" CheckBox not staying checked

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am having problems with my login page. It pulls through the Username correctly from the cookie, however the CheckBox for Remember Me does not become checked when I view the page, even though the code for setting it on the Page_Load is being executed.

LoggedIn event for setting the cookies

```
    protected void lLogin_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If Remember me then set an appropriate cookie
        if (lLogin.RememberMeSet)
        {
            HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("loginCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Remove("loginCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
            loginCookie.Values.Add("username", lLogin.UserName.ToString());
            DateTime dtExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
            Response.Cookies["loginCookie"].Expires = dtExpiry;
        }

        // Set a cookie to expire after 1 second
        else
        {
            HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("loginCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Remove("loginCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
            loginCookie.Values.Add("username", lLogin.UserName.ToString());
            DateTime dtExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1); //you can add years and months too here
            Response.Cookies["loginCookie"].Expires = dtExpiry;
        }
    }
```

Page_Load event for Login page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get username field to set focus
        TextBox txtUserName = (TextBox)lLogin.FindControl("UserName");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // For resetting the login url so that it doesn't have a return value in the URL
            if (Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
            }


            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Main/Home.aspx", true);
            }

            // If login cookie exists pull username
            if (Request.Cookies["loginCookie"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie loginCookie = Request.Cookies["loginCookie"];
                lLogin.UserName = loginCookie.Values["username"].ToString();
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)lLogin.FindControl("RememberMe");
                // This is being Executed which is why I am puzzled
                cb.Checked = true;
            }
        }

        this.SetFocus(txtUserName);         
    }
```

My Web.Config  contains the following information as well as a MachineKey, Is this correct?

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60000" name="HRKCO" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc"  cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30"/>
```

**EDIT**

I solved this problem by using:

```
lLogin.RememberMeSet = true;
```

I assumed this would be the same as finding the RememberMe CheckBox and setting the checked state but obviously it was not. Just thought I would share this if anyone else was having similar problems.

Comment: Not staying checked ? or not getting the check value correctly ?

Comment: lLogin is the Login control. It's not staying checked - even though cb.CHecked = true :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to my problem was the way in which I was setting the checkbox in the `Page_Load` Event.

**Solution**

```
// If login cookie exists pull username
    if (Request.Cookies["loginCookie"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie loginCookie = Request.Cookies["loginCookie"];
        lLogin.UserName = loginCookie.Values["username"].ToString();
        lLogin.RememberMeSet = true;
    }
```

Comment: i was going to suggest that this is likely the intended behavior. If the user *has* the cookie, that mean they already checked the checkbox and logged in. Ideally the user will never see the login prompt/remember me checkbox again (because they should automatically login with the cookie). Unless the user manually clicked **Logout**. In that case there would be no existing *login cookie*, because it is deleted on logout, and the next time they try to login the checkbox will (and should) be unchecked.

Comment: i was confused at first too. *i swear i checked the checkbox already*. Then i realized the only reason i was seeing the checkbox again was because i wasn't logged in.

Answer (score 1):

In the `forms` element of your `web.config`, have you tried the `cookieless="UseCookies"` attribute?  I see that you have it for `sessionState`, but I believe you need it for `forms` too.

Answer (score 0):

Set RememberMeSet="true" to asp:Login control

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" RememberMeSet="true" ... >
```